# Emacs 28.2 error in macOS Ventura: `image-type: Invalid image type ‘svg’`

Tags: osx

since upgrading to macOS Ventura, my Emacs 28.2 installation throws the error message `image-type: Invalid image type ‘svg’` at the startup of Emacs.

`M-: (image-type-available-p 'svg) RET`
returns `t`.

Might someone know why this error occurs and how to resolve it? \

EDIT: In answer to a comment, the value of `image-types` is `(png gif tiff jpeg xpm xbm pbm)` - note that `svg` is *not* a member of that list.

Also, the value of `image-use-external-converter` is `nil`.

I just installed version 28.2 of Emacs (released 2022-09-12) from [here](https://emacsformacosx.com/builds)  on Ventura 13.0.1.

Unfortunately, I upgraded to Ventura prematurely. Now both emacs and Google Drive no longer works. I'm hoping to find a solution to both problems or to downgrade to the previous version of MacOS Monterey 12.x. I'm hoping to get some help on these issues. I do not have enough reputation points on this site yet.

Comment: I am stumped by exactly the same problem. My emacs is from https://emacsformacosx.com/: GNU Emacs 28.2 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0, NS appkit-1671.60 Version 10.14.6 (Build 18G95)) of 2022-09-12
Could it be specific to this version?

Comment: Same for me. I installed emacs homebrew cask on new machine, just after upgrade to Ventura. I don't have the same problem on my work Monterey machine.

Comment: Do `C-h v image-types` - does it include `svg`? Also do `C-h v image-use-external-converter` - what is its value?

Comment: Does this occur if you start with `emacs -Q`? If not, search your init file for `image-type`. If you don't find anything, try `emacs --debug-init` and see if you get a backtrace. If you do, edit your question and add it.

Answer (score 14):

This is an issue with the way Emacs initializes its image support on macOS Ventura. It's fixed on the current master branch, and will be in Emacs 29 when that is released.

See https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=59081

Comment: Can you provide a link to the bug report/fix?

Comment: @NickD done (although the commit doesn't have a bug# in it, <sigh>)

Comment: There is a reply to the bug report mentioning  a couple of commits. So if somebody is determined enough, they can find their way to a fix, although admittedly they would have to know their way around `git` to do so. Maybe the fix can be backported to Emacs 28?

Comment: There are no more releases of emacs-28 planned: the start of the release stabilization for emacs-29 is imminent. But if you can pin down exactly which commits are needed you can try to convince Eli

Comment: The bug number is in the link (59081), but it's not needed. The information in the report is sufficient to solve the problem, this did it for me:
    `git clone https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs.git`  
    `cd emacs`
 `git checkout -b svg-fix-28.2 emacs-28.2` 
    `git cherry-pick 5f8c655a44a0e7ad1fe6f8b23acb4e6c93dc72a6 44138d5ecce275caef9efe0ae4f4a89e4a33b588`  
    `./autogen.sh`    
    `make`  
    `./src/emacs`  
Detailed information are in the INSTALL file. (I don't have reputation enough to answer the question properly though.)

Answer (score 11):

I tried a little workaround to see if it works - overriding image-type-available-p like this:

```
;; overriding image.el function image-type-available-p
(defun image-type-available-p (type)
  "Return t if image type TYPE is available.
Image types are symbols like `xbm' or `jpeg'."
  (if (eq 'svg type)
      nil
    (and (fboundp 'init-image-library)
         (init-image-library type))))
```

This seems to make elfeed and eww work without throwing errors.

Hope it helps things work for you until there Emacs 29 is released.

Comment: That didn't work for me but after a bit of research into the cause I added `(add-to-list 'image-types 'svg)` to my Emacs config and now everything is working.

Answer (score 9):

This seems to only happen when you have an `.emacs` file. I too just installed Emacs with `brew install --cask emacs` and it was working fine until I added an `.emacs` file. (I compulsively disable `tool-bar-mode` for all eternity before I puke.)

Based on other answers here, adding this brief stanza to the beginning of my `.emacs` allowed Emacs to work without the warning again.

```
(setq image-types (cons 'svg image-types))
```

This is basically the same as [George Mauer's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/77169/2057) except it uses the previous value of `image-types` and prepends `svg` in front, rather than hard-coding the entire list.

Comment: This works for the emacsformacosx.com version, which is still 28.2 in 2023/07

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% clear what other impacts it has. You can see the error comes from this code:

```
  (when (and (not (eq type 'image-convert))
             (not (memq type (and (boundp 'image-types) image-types))))
```

Simply adding `svg` to the `image-types` list fixed it for me.

```
(setq image-types '(svg png gif tiff jpeg xpm xbm pbm))
```