# Can I display svg in emacs on mac / osx?

Tags: osx, image-mode

I briefly tried to display svg images in emacs on mac.

Supposedly emacs has [svg support](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsSvg) which requires on `librsvg2`. But I get  `Cannot display image: (Invalid image type ‘svg’)`
when I run `M-x image-mode` in an open svg file.

I seem to have librsvg2 installed with brew:

`/usr/local/Cellar/librsvg/2.54.5/lib/librsvg-2.2.dylib`

Comment: See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74289/emacs-28-2-error-in-macos-ventura-image-type-invalid-image-type-svg

Comment: Ah awesome - let me close this as a duplicate